# How to fix errorerror trying to update table in sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying with a database (sql) to update elements from the front using ejs and exprees but when I am in the template to edit when I make the call in the form to send the data I get the error can not POST / update I think the error is here `<form action="/update/<%= book.id %>" method="POST">` since that is when I press the send button that sends that error.

this is to have a simple page to show the saved data and be able to manipulate them with the front but I do not know if my error is in the routes or in the controller

edit.ejs file

```
<form action="/update/<%= book.id %>" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="bookName">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameinput"  placeholder="Book name" name="name" value="<%= book.name %>">
    </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

my controller.js

```
controller.edit = (req, res) => {
  const connection = getConnection();
  const { id } = req.params;
  const queryString = 'SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = ?';
  connection.query(queryString, [id], (err, rows, foundBook, foundId) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.render('edit', { book: foundBook, id: foundId });
  });
};

controller.update = (req, res) => {

  const name = req.body;
  // const author = req.body.updateAutor;
  // const description = req.body.createDescription;
  // const price = req.body.updatePrice;
  // const genre = req.body.updateGenre;
  // const image = req.body.create_image;
  const { id } = req.params;
  const queryString = 'UPDATE book SET ? WHERE id = ?';

  req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query(queryString, [name, id], (err, rows) =>{
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

my routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const customerController = require('../controllers/booksConstrollers');
const router = express.Router();
let obj = {}; // create a array to get info from db in get router



router.get('/', customerController.list);
router.get('/add', customerController.add);
router.post('/add', customerController.save);
router.get('/details/:id', customerController.details);
router.get('/update/:id', customerController.edit);
router.post('/update/:id', customerController.update);
//router.get('/delete/:id', customerController.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You have a `console.log(err)` -- does it produce an error? I think your UPDATE is not correct because it should be like `UPDATE book SET column_name = ? WHERE id = ?`. You can use parameters only in a place where you would use a single scalar value, not expressions or clauses of SQL syntax.

Comment: @BillKarwin in the console does not produce any errors only in the browser route error ` can not POST / update `

Comment: @liantony.p if you are using `node.js`, your routes and controller pages should have a `.js` extension, and not a `.ejs`.

Comment: `.ejs` is for your html templates *only*

Comment: sorry @Jane my mistake in the post my js file extension is ok